# Insert title page into table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I'm trying to format a thesis to university requirements. The university requires the front matter to conform to the following:

- Everything up to the table of contents has a roman page number (but this isn't displayed on the title page)
- The table of contents includes entries for the title page, abstract, and table of contents, with their roman page number listed.

I can't seem to get either of these things right. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
%for split boxes and title page
\usepackage{array}
%for title page
\usepackage{graphicx}
%for double spacing in abstract
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{title.tex}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
 \vspace*{1in}
 \MakeUppercase{The Title of}\\[12pt]
 \MakeUppercase{My Thesis}\\
 % ----------------------------------------------------------------
 \vspace{1.5cm}
 by\\[12pt]
 Nathan G. Glenn\\[14pt]
  % ----------------------------------------------------------------
 \vspace{2cm}
Submitted to Brigham Young University in partial fulfillment of\\[12pt] graduation requirements for University Honors \\[5pt]

 \vfill
 % ----------------------------------------------------------------

Linguistics Department\\[12pt]
Some University\\[12pt]
{November 2012}
 \vfill

\begin{tabbing}%
   \hspace{3in}\= \kill % set up one tab position
   \centering\arraybackslash Advisor: My Advisor  \> Honors Representative: My Rep\\[12pt]
   \centering\arraybackslash Signature: \hspace{0.5cm}\makebox[1.8in]{\hrulefill} \> Signature: \hspace{0.5cm} \makebox[1.8in]{\hrulefill}
\end{tabbing}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{abstract.tex}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1in}
ABSTRACT\\[36pt]

\MakeUppercase{The Title of}\\[12pt]
\MakeUppercase{My Thesis}\\[36pt]

Nathan G. Glenn\\[12pt]
Linguistics Department\\[12pt]
Bachelor of Arts\\[36pt]

\end{center}
\doublespacing
Is the page number roman like it should be?

\singlespacing
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{title.tex}
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Abstract}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Title and Abstract Should Appear Above Me in the ToC}
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{LitReview}
\end{document}
```

If you compile this, you will see that I have not managed to make the front matter use roman lettering, and I haven't even attempted to add the front matter items to the ToC because I do not know how. Can anyone show me how to do this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following seems to adhere to your request (mildly different from Guido's answer):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
%for split boxes and title page
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
%for title page
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
%for double spacing in abstract
\usepackage{setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\thispagestyle{empty}

% --- begin title.tex

%\begin{titlepage}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}The title of my thesis}% Add title to ToC
\begin{center}
 \vspace*{1in}
 \MakeUppercase{The Title of}\\[12pt]
 \MakeUppercase{My Thesis}\\
 % ----------------------------------------------------------------
 \vspace{1.5cm}
 by\\[12pt]
 Nathan G. Glenn\\[14pt]
  % ----------------------------------------------------------------
 \vspace{2cm}
Submitted to Brigham Young University in partial fulfillment of\\[12pt] graduation requirements for University Honors \\[5pt]

 \vfill
 % ----------------------------------------------------------------

Linguistics Department\\[12pt]
Some University\\[12pt]
{November 2012}
 \vfill

\begin{tabbing}%
   \hspace{3in}\= \kill % set up one tab position
   \centering\arraybackslash Advisor: My Advisor  \> Honors Representative: My Rep\\[12pt]
   \centering\arraybackslash Signature: \hspace{0.5cm}\makebox[1.8in]{\hrulefill} \> Signature: \hspace{0.5cm} \makebox[1.8in]{\hrulefill}
\end{tabbing}
\end{center}
%\end{titlepage}

% --- end title.tex

\clearpage

% --- begin abstract.tex

\begin{center}
\vspace*{1in}
ABSTRACT\\[36pt]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}My abstract}% Add abstract to ToC


\MakeUppercase{The Title of}\\[12pt]
\MakeUppercase{My Thesis}\\[36pt]

Nathan G. Glenn\\[12pt]
Linguistics Department\\[12pt]
Bachelor of Arts\\[36pt]

\end{center}
\doublespacing
Is the page number arabic like it should be?

\singlespacing

% --- end abstract.tex

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

{
\makeatletter
\let\@oldstarttoc\@starttoc
\renewcommand{\@starttoc}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\contentsname}% Add ToC to ToC
  \@oldstarttoc
}
\tableofcontents
\makeatother
}
\chapter{Title and Abstract Should Appear Above Me in the ToC}
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{LitReview}
\end{document}
```

Instead of using the `titlepage` environment, I've used `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\thispagestyle{empty}`, to remove the page numbering. For each of the title, abstract and contents, I've added a `\addtocontents{toc}{chapter}{...}` which sets the entry in the ToC similar to that of the chapters. This can be changed, of course.

Also, instead of loading the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and patching `\tableofcontents`, a localized redefinition of `\@starttoc` is sufficient to add the ToC to the ToC itself.

Comment: Great, thanks! I also needed the ToC to be roman numbered, so I moved \pagenumbering{arabic} to right after the first chapter heading.

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after `\tableofcontents` otherwise the page number for the abstract and the table of contents will be in arabic numerals and not roman.

Eventually, you might add a line `\addtocounter{page}{1}` after `\end{titlepage}` (`titlepage` resets the counter of the page at the end to 1, so the nex page after it is page 1)>

To add the title page and abstract to the content you can add the line

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<TEXT>}
```

somewhere in the title page file and at the  beginning of the abstract file. Replace `<TEXT>` with whatever appropriate for the context.

For the table of contents, you can use the `etoolbox` package to patch it

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\@starttoc}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}\@starttoc}
  {}
  {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
%for split boxes and title page
\usepackage{array}
%for title page
\usepackage{graphicx}
%for double spacing in abstract
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{title.tex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
 \vspace*{1in}
 \MakeUppercase{The Title of}\\[12pt]
 \MakeUppercase{My Thesis}\\
\end{center}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{abstract.tex}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1in}
\chapter*{ABSTRACT}

\MakeUppercase{The Title of}\\[12pt]
\MakeUppercase{My Thesis}\\[36pt]

Nathan G. Glenn\\[12pt]
Linguistics Department\\[12pt]
Bachelor of Arts\\[36pt]
\end{center}
\doublespacing
Is the page number arabic like it should be?
\singlespacing
\end{filecontents}

\newenvironment{romanpages}
{\setcounter{page}{1}\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}}
{\cleardoublepage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}\setcounter{page}{1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{romanpages}
  \input{title}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title}
  \input{abstract}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\end{romanpages}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Title and Abstract Should Appear Above Me in the ToC}
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{LitReview}
\end{document}
```

I have added a new environment called roman pages. Also, I have added `\addcontentsline` command to include title and abstract. Also, add `\thispagestyle{empty}` in `title.tex` to suppress the page number.